# Layout issue with Spyder (Python 3.8)

Tags: python, layout, anaconda, spyder, anaconda3

I restarted Spyder on my desktop and it looks like all of the consoles and files have become minimized. I am assuming there is an easy fix for this, but I am not sure since I just started using the program. Please help!

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Could you edit your question and post a screenshot of what you're seeing? That will help me to better understand your problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.